# Positioning div centered relatively to another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working in some sort of overlay to state that the page (or some element) is being loaded. I'm trying to position the `div` which says: "Loading..." positioned in the center either of the page or the element being targeted.

This is my approach, but it isn't working at all...

```
var left, top,
    position = 'fixed';

if (this.container !== 'body'){
  position = 'absolute';
}

left = (window.innerWidth - this.element.offsetWidth) / 2;
top = (window.innerHeight/2) - (this.element.offsetHeight/ 2);

this.modal.style.left = left + 'px';
this.modal.style.top = top + 'px';
this.modal.style.position = position;
```

Please, state that there is no jQuery and I don't intend using jQuery.

Comment: Why don't you use css?

Comment: Because the element on which position I need to relay is uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the same div for all action notifications, I mean different elements, but the same div, you won't be able to do it without using JS. But at least jQuery would make it easier to code:

You can [.offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to find out current element position relative to whole document and `.height()` with `.width()` of element to calculate your popup coordinates.

Comment: I do want to use JavaScript, there is no way in which this could be made only using CSS. And jQuery is off the table.

Comment: In this case I'd recomment you to just get those 3 methods of jQuery to your application. It will allow you to have cross browser solution. What the reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: It's not necessary to add jQuery to the page for everything!

Comment: Ok. Then just take only those methods, and make your own small lib.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use css to center the "cover" over the loading part, then use jquery to hide the "cover" div when completed.

<html>
    <style>
        #outer
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #loading
        {
            position: absolute; 
            background-color: blue; 
            width: 200px; 
            height: 200px; 
            margin-left: -100px; 
            left: 50%; 
            margin-top: -100px; 
            top: 50%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#loading").hide();
        });
    </script>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="loading">

        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work if I want it to be in the middle of the div with id of `awesomeContentThatStillHaventLoad`

Comment: What does your html look like? is this in another div?

Comment: This is sort of a plugin, I cannot know which is going to be the content inside the page and maybe the `container` is not body but whichever other element in the page. I want to cover the element with an overlay and a message saying that's being loaded. That's why CSS solution cannot work

Comment: in otehr words you want to remove the cover after the content has loaded?

Comment: Sorry but doesn't meet any requirements: 1st is using jQuery, second your divs aren't positioned against any elements. I want to grab a DOM element and position a DIV according to that grabbed element.

Comment: This was first only to center an element. Now its more. I have a div(which is an element) inside another div and then centered it. I thought that was the requirement from the start. The outer div can be ANYWHERE. even inside another element or whatever. I just centered it. you can still cover the inner div 100% so that it is covered. but clearly you did not just want to center your "cover"

Comment: I think it's pretty clear in the original post: `...in the center either of the page or the element being targeted`. Also, since it needs different positioning (fixed or absolute), it needs a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out:

```
var left, top,
    position = 'fixed';

if (this.container !== 'body'){
  position = 'absolute';
}
var rect = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();

left = Math.round(((rect.width - this.modal.offsetWidth) / 2) + rect.left);
top = Math.round(((rect.height - this.modal.offsetHeight) / 2) + rect.top);

this.modal.style.left = left + 'px';
this.modal.style.top = top + 'px';
this.modal.style.position = position;
```

This will center the element correctly inside of a given element.